# Extending my Java API to C++ through JNI: How to wrap a method returning a String?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to extend my API in Java, in order to make it accessible through C++ (I am creating wrapper classes). I am experienced in Java but new to C++.

Now, I am creating a wrapper in C++ for a Java function getString() which returns a String. I am using GetStringUTFChars to get the C string from the Java String but I don't know where to use ReleaseStringUTFChars which releases the C string. Here is my code (aClass and aClassInstance are private date members inside the wrapper class):

```
const char* getString() {
jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(aClass,
        "methodName",
        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
if (methodID == NULL) {
    cout << "--methodID = NULL";
    exit(0);
}
jstring jstringResult = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(aClassInstance, methodID);
const char* result = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstringResult, NULL);
// env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstringResult, result); 
return result;
}
```

If I remove the // and use ReleaseStringUTFChars, result will be released and I will no longer be able to return it, right? Should I copy result to another char array before releasing it?

Thanks, any help is welcome!

K

Comment: Use std::string, if possible.

Comment: @Mahesh Why? const char* is not a problem, where to use ReleaseStringUTFChars is my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mahesh is right

```
std::string getString()
{
    jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID(aClass,
        "methodName",
        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (methodID == NULL)
    {
        cout << "--methodID = NULL";
        exit(0);
    }
    jstring jstringResult = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(aClassInstance, methodID);
    const char* result = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstringResult, NULL);
    std::string result2(result);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstringResult, result); 
    return result2;
}
```

std::string takes copies your characters for you and will automatically free when needed. Using raw pointers in C++ is generally frowned upon. Coming from Java you probably have little idea of the problems they can cause.

Comment: I wouldn't say using pointers is frowned upon.  I would rather say they're not best practice.  Using pointers *can* make a part of a program cleaner.  I also wouldn't assume OP is not familiar / good at C++.  Just because they're using Java doesn't mean they only know Java.

Comment: Thanx John. That's more or less what I thought which also applies for char arrays. It seems silly to have both result and result2 but I guess it's the only way since result needs to be released before returning. I didn't know this about not using raw pointers, I will adopt it.

Comment: @André Caron I've yet to see a program where using `char*` is cleaner than `std::string`. Heck even in C no sane person handles native char arrays anymore if not necessary - there are enough good libraries for that. And Kostis actually you create at least two strings here if the c++ compiler couldn't transform the code (it can though) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious place to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` is in your wrapper class' destructor. Use a `vector` or some other container to record each jstring as it's accessed, and then in your wrapper class' destructor, call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` on every element in the container. Your clients will need to make copies of the character data if they live longer than the wrapper class object.